# php script isnt opening the welcome page nor writing to the database with wamp

Tags: php, mysql

Am not being able to get any information into my wamp server database nor will it display the welcome page below is my code can someone please tell me what am doing wrong or if my wamp maybe configured wrong?

php code below

```
<?
// Test if submit button was pressed
if (isset($_POST['sub_button'])) { 

    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $sex=$_POST['sex'];
    $address=$_POST['add'];
    $email=$_POST['e_address'];
    $years=$_POST['n_years'];
    $favSong=$_POST['f_song'];
    // Create the connection to the server
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";

    $con=mysqli_connect($ db_host, $db_username, $db_passwod); // to connect to the database server

    // to check the connection to the server
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo"Failed to connect to my SQL:" .mysqli_connect_errno();// if there is an error this shows up.
    }
    // this selects the database 

    mysqli.select_db($con, 'fan'); // ensure that the database has the same name as your created database.

    //Insert Statement
    //Values of fname, lname etc is the exact name spelling from the html file.
    //Values of $title $fname are the values from the php which stores the variables name.
    $sql="INSERT INTO information(fname, lname, sex, add, e_address, n_years, f_song)
            VALUES('$fname','$lname','$sex','$address','$email','$years','$favSong')";
    //Check if insert successful.
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        header("Location:welcome.html");
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error;".mysqli_error($con);
    }

}//closing the "IF isset" statement.

//php closing.
?>
```

Comment: your apache web server is started? can you post a print of the wamp / panel application where he shows the status of its services?

Comment: Please put your `mysqli_close` before the redirect header. And try adding a space between the colon and `welcome.html`.

Comment: @MarceloBezerra how do I do that? am new to wamp server

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html

Comment: @iamsleepy I tried your method but its still not working

Comment: @MarceloBezerra here is a dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/2p6p5yj9mmo88rf/Capture.PNG

Comment: i will try it in my wamp server and tell you what happens

Comment: Ah sorry, that was an improvement suggestion not an answer. Any error from the log ? And one more thing, you declared `$db_password` but you passed `$db_passwod` to the connection string.

Comment: `mysqli.select_db($con, 'fan');` should be  `mysqli_select_db($con, 'fan');`

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at my code over and over i notice i was missing

Correct code

`<?php

               ?>`

instead I had

`<?

                 ?>`